Salop linear Model - Asymmetric
In a circular city model a la Salop consumers have a linear transportation cost t for each unit they
have to travel. The length of the full circle is normalized to 1. Two firms are active in the market,
have no production cost and are located at 0 and ½ and set prices. The equilibrium level of prices can be calculated easily, and if I´m not mistaken it will equal 1. However, they also ask the following:  Suppose then that a third firm is contemplating to enter. Firm 1 and 2 cannot change their locations anymore and firm 3 thinks about entering at ¼. There is a fixed cost f of entry.
b. If entry takes place what are the equilibrium prices in the market. Which firm charges the lowest market price and provide an economic explanation for that result? (Hint: note that firm 1 and 2 are still symmetric to each other, but firm 3 is not).
I´m not sure how to solve it as I have never seen a Salop linear model with asymmetrical firms
c. For which level of fixed cost f does a third firm not want to enter the market?

Your answer for the case of two firms is wrong as the expression for the equilibrium prices must involve $t$. (Or perhaps you have set $t$ to some value in your answer?)

For the three firm case, assume firm $1$ is located at $0$ (or $1$) and that firm $2$ is located at $1/2$. Let $x_{12}\in(1/2,1)$, $x_{13}\in(0,1/4)$, and $x_{23}\in(1/4,1/2)$ denote the locations of the consumers indifferent between $1$ and $2$, between $1$ and $3$, and between $2$ and $3$.
[If there is a pure strategy Nash equilibrium in prices (added in edit after Giskard's comment), then they must all exist: If not, then at least one firm would have no demand and could do better by lowering its price, or a firm is pricing below zero and so could do better by raising its price.]
We have:
$$\begin{align*}
t(1-x_{12})+p_1&=t(x_{12}-1/2)+p_2\\
tx_{13}+p_1&=t(1/4-x_{13})+p_3\\
t(1/2-x_{23})+p_2&=t(x_{13}-1/4)+p_3\\
\end{align*}$$
Thus:
$$\begin{align*}
x_{12}&=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{p_1-p_2}{2t}\\
x_{13}&=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{p_3-p_1}{2t}\\ 
x_{23}&=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{p_2-p_3}{2t}
 \end{align*}$$
The profits of each firm are:
$$\begin{align*}
\pi_1(p)&=p_1(1-x_{12}+x_{13})\\
\pi_2(p)&=p_2(x_{12}-x_{23})\\
\pi_3(p)&=p_3(x_{23}-x_{13})
 \end{align*}$$
and
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \pi_1}{\partial p_1}&=(1-x_{12}+x_{13})-\frac{p_1}{t}=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{p_2+p_3-4p_1}{2t}\\
\frac{\partial \pi_2}{\partial p_2}&=(x_{12}-x_{23})-\frac{p_2}{t}=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{p_1+p_3-4p_2}{2t}\\
\frac{\partial \pi_3}{\partial p_3}&=(x_{23}-x_{13})-\frac{p_3}{t}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{p_1+p_2-4p_3}{2t}
 \end{align*}$$
Setting each equation to zero and solving gives $p_1^*=p_2^*=7t/20$ and $p_3^*=3t/10$. In equilibrium we have $x_{12}^*=3/4$, $x_{13}^*=1/10$, $x_{23}^*=2/5$ and profits are:
$$\begin{align*}
\pi_1^*=\pi_2^*&=\frac{49t}{400}\\
\pi_3^*&=\frac{9t}{100}
 \end{align*}$$
This is not the Nash equilibrium for the reason pointed about by Giskard in the first comment, so it seems there is no pure strategy Nash equilibrium.

The rest of this answer is based on the incorrect solution above.

Firm $3$ prices lower than firms $1$ and $2$. The intuition is that firms $1$ and $2$ face less price competition between each other than with firm $3$ because $1$ and $2$ are further apart from each other (distance $1/2$) than from $3$ (distance $1/4$). Firm $3$ faces the same level of price competition with both firms $1$ and $2$ as it is closer to both (at a distance of $1/4$ from both).
Mathematically, notice that for any firm $i$ the profit/revenue is
$$\pi_i(p)=p_iD_i(p)$$
where $D_i$ is the demand function of firm $i$. The marginal revenue for firm $i$ is
$$\frac{\partial \pi_i}{\partial p_i}=D_i(p)+p_i\frac{\partial D_i}{\partial p_i}\tag{1}$$
Every firm has has $\partial D_i/\partial p_i=-1/t$. If all firms were to have the same price, then:

The second term in $(1)$ would be the same for all firms, i.e. a marginal increase in price would cause the same marginal reduction in revenue (through reduction in demand).
The first term (the quantity demanded) in $(1)$ would be larger ($3/8$) for firms $1$ and $2$ than for firm $3$ ($1/4$). (This is why firms $1$ and $2$ face softer price competition: they are competing over more consumers.)
This cannot be an equilibrium. Firms $1$ and $2$ would have a marginal revenue that is larger than firm $3$ and so either firms $1$ and $2$ would want to raise their price or firm $3$ would want to lower its price.


For the last part, any fixed cost $f>\pi^*_3=9t/100$.

I think the spectre of D'Aspremont et al. is looming over your solution, as you are only considering the marginal optimality of $3$'s pricing (e.g. you assume an indifferent buyer $x_{23}$ exists). But firm $3$ could totally undercut the others by pricing at $p_3 = 0.099t$, and attain a higher profit ($0.099t$ vs $0.09t$). Caveat emptor: I only calculated this in my head.

True. I had assumed because this looked like a homework or textbook problem that it would be straightforward, so hadn't bothered to check that possibility. I suppose there must be no pure strategy equilibrium then?

I am just guessing, but I also don't think that 1) there is a pure strategy equilirium 2) the professor who assigned this exercise thought of this problem.

I don't understand how the Q is getting more votes than your A? Here, have one.
